# C# .NET 2.0 components

Tags: c#, .net

How can I check what objects, tools, variables, anything... are used from .NET 2.0 in a C# application.

How can I get a C# application run without .NET 2.0 ?

UPDATE:
sorry, I didn't clarify enought. Here's my situation: I have developed a pretty simple application in C#: embeded browser which displayes static webpages with an option of searching inside of these html pages. I'm using simple textbox, buttons components for this.

The application will be distribuited for people wich have very old PCs, even with windows 95. I would like the app to be runable on it, or at least on win 98, without telling the people to install .NET 2.0, as the users don;t really have PC usage skills :) .

I'm using a dataGridView as well.

Comment: What do you mean "without .net 2.0"? You can use other versions of the framework, such as 3.5 or 4.0 but you will always need SOME version of the framework to run a C# app (which is essentially a .net app, written in C#).

Comment: my app has to run on windows 98 for example. without installing any update of .NET. If not possible then on Windows XP

Comment: Could you create an installer that bundles the .net redistributable and installs in for them if necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at this : http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/

> "The mini-deployment tool puts
>   together the minimum set of CLR
>   runtime files and dependent assemblies
>   that can be simply copied to a single
>   folder on a target machine, and your
>   application runs as if the whole
>   framework is installed. Since the
>   installation is isolated into a single
>   folder, there will be no conflicts
>   with future .NET installation. When
>   linking is used for the dependent
>   assemblies, it will further reduce the
>   file size."

Answer (score 3):

You may need to clarify a bit more.. do you want the app to run without .Net at all? Or you want it to run in .Net 3.5 without .net 2.0 bits?

If its the latter, then simply don't reference assemblies that are compiled in .net 2.0 (check the properties on the reference you have added). If its the former, then its really not feasable. Yes its possible, but it means deploying parts of the framework with your app, but then, you'd be deploying all the bits, including the 2.0 bits.

Your're question really needs more information though, it doesn't make much sense currently. Sorry. =)

Answer (score 1):

To make sure it runs without .NET 2.0, compile it with the .NET 1.1 compiler.

But this seems like not a good idea. I'd recommend revisiting your requirements. 
Win98 wasn't shipped with .NET.  Using .NET v1.1 won't get you much more platform penetration than .NET 2.0, if any.

Answer (score 0):

IT looks like windows 98 supports the .net framework.  See this answer for details:

[OS Compatibility for various .NET Framework versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198873/os-compatibility-for-various-net-frameworks)

Comment: He is specific that users will not have to install the .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a .NET application (i.e., that uses the CLR) if you haven't installed the corresponding .NET Framework binaries (i.e., that contains the CLR) directly or indirectly.

Period.