# Windows 3.11 version .net

Tags: .net, windows

I am currently developing a brand new hex editor for Windows 3.11, and I was wondering if I could use the latest version of .net.

Does windows 3.11 support .net 4.5 ?

Update:
Apparently there is no possiblity to run .net 4.5, but is there any emulators or virtualization (vmware) for windows 3.11, so it will be possible to "hack in" .net versions?

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/198925/650012) SO answer there is a list of Windows versions vs. .NET Framework versions. From this list you may conclude that Windows 98 is the earliest OS to support any version of .NET.

Comment: "HA HA HA, OH WOW.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

No, Windows 3.11 dates from the early 1990s and as such pre-dates .net by a loooong time. You cannot run any version of .net on Windows 3.11, never mind bleeding edge .net 4.5.