# What maximum .NET version can be installed on old OS?

Tags: c#, .net, operating-system

I am not very experienced .NET programmer and I am developing a small app using WPF. I want to use .NET Frmwk v4.5. However, I'd like to make my app available not only on Win 8, but on old OSes (like Win 7 and Vista) too. As far as I know, Win 7 is shipped with .NET v3.5 and Vista has v2.0 or v3.0. I build a small tool using C to detect .NET version and ask end user if he wants to install latest version to run my main app. 
The question is: is there a maximum version of .NET that can be installed on a particular OS? Win 7 and 8 can deal with v4.5.1, but what about Vista? Or even XP? Is it possible to install .NET 4.5 on XP? 
Sorry if my question is stupid and thanks in advance!

Comment: A duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198873/os-compatibility-for-various-net-framework-versions

Comment: Also from MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.5 cannot be installed on Windows XP (only .NET 4).