# How to run a C# application on WindowsNT?

Tags: c#, .net-1.1, windows-nt

On trying to run a c# hello world program on Windows NT4 SP6a, the error message says .net dll's not found; however on trying to install .net framework 1.1 on WinNT i get an error: "*Application has generated an exception that could not be handled*". When i run the C# app on Windows 7 there are no issues.

Comment: Windows NT? .NET 1.1? Are we in 2001 or what happened here? Also, not sure if this is a programming question, sounds like a better fit for Server Fault

Comment: Many developers have to work on/support legacy applications nowadays, I posted in the hope that someone may find it useful

Comment: Not for operating systems that are over 20 years old and haven't been supported for almost as long though. Also, this question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @DavidG Security? What's that?

Comment: It's a QA-style answer, and I can see this is totally relevant for one poor developer having to support this. It doesn't matter if such an environment is hopelessly out of date or not. We get plenty of VB6 questions which is even older than NT4.

Comment: @Lennart No, this question (as already pointed out by Camilo) is off topic here, but may work on SF.

Comment: I agree that the question is a perfectly valid one and deserves an answer, however, it's nothing about programming, ServerFault, or maybe SuperUser, seems better candidates to host this.

Comment: You need SP6a, not SP6 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26

Comment: This question should NOT have been closed as off-topic. .NET 1.1 is a programming framework and issues with installation are absolutely within the scope of SO. However... this question is NOT well researched. It should have been closed as a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198873/os-compatibility-for-various-net-framework-versions (Windows NT is not a supported OS for .NET 1.1)

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367443/how-to-migrate-question-about-an-obsolete-os).

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 supports the latest .NET framework whereas WinNT supports only .NET 1.1 and installing .NET 1.1 on WinNT is not straightforward.

To get over those errors, do the following:

1. To fix this we need to copy a folder from a Windows Server 2003 machine to WinNT machine.
2. Find a Windows Server 2003 machine on which .NET framework is already installed.
3. From the Win 2003 machine copy "Framework" folder [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework]
4. Create a folder "Microsoft.NET" in WinNT machine at [C:\Winnt\Microsoft.NET]
5. Copy the "Framework" folder from step-3 to "Microsoft.NET" folder in WinNT machine (step-4).
6. Now you have [C:\Winnt\Microsoft.NET\Framework] folder structure in the WinNT machine.
7. Run dotnetfx.exe and the installation should complete without incident.

[reference](https://www.petri.com/installing-net-framework-1-1-on-windows-nt-4-0-server)

Comment: Also make sure that you are running on service pack 6a: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26

Comment: [Looks like with NT SP6a and IE 6.0 SP1 , .NET 1.1 is officially supported](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26). There are no special installation instructions provided, so the installer should work as it is with that setup.